# Update to Ubuntu Base broke my OS

Tags: updates

I'm pretty new to Linux. I run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an Intel Compute Stick model STK2m3W64CC. It's been awesome, but a recent update left me with a broken OS. I get the boot splash, then a blank screen with a blinking white terminal cursor and nothing else. If I start in recovery mode and then choose continue it starts up and everything seems normal except that says the graphics card is now llvmpipe instead of the Intel 515 Skylake.

So I restored my OS partion from the backup that I obviously made right before installing updates, and tried updates again choosing only the Ubuntu Base update, and same problem so I think that narrows down the cause.

So what should I do? Should I just stop updating the Ubuntu base, or is there something else I can try to fix this? Thanks in advance everyone.

Update 2020-02-10:
Maybe this doesn't narrow down the cause, because I tried install all the updates EXCEPT Ubuntu Base and the same thing happened. I also discovered that if I leave it on the blinking cursor screen for long enough (like 15 min+) then I get this screen: [image: boot error screen] Does this help at all?

To see what is in /var/log/apt/history.log I'd have to install the updates and break my system again, and then it takes a while to restore that partition back so I am hesitant to do that unless I get a big enough block of free time.

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: And what is "Ubuntu base"?

Comment: I don't know what the "Ubuntu Base" update actually updates...that's why I'm posting this question really. If I'm missing an update to "Ubuntu Base" then am I missing something important?

I've restored my os partition from my pre-update backup, so I assume "boot from a previous kernel" is what I'm doing really. Is there a way to roll back to a previous kernel without restoring from my backup?

Comment: Not long ago 18.04 upgraded kernel to 5.3. But you can boot with a previous 5.0 kernel using grub. That doesn't mean restore from a backup. Did you install any graphics drivers before?

Comment: I may have installed some graphics drivers at some point, but certainly not immediate before the update. Is there a way I can check what graphics drivers I'm using?

Comment: It doesn't matter when. It is generally a bad idea to install any Intel drivers. Now they are incompatible with the new kernel and it is hard to remove them.

Comment: You can press "e" to edit on the grub screen and then scroll down to the line with `linux /boot/` and then go to the end of the line after `splash` and leave one blank space and then type: `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` and then use CTRL+X to boot. If this works, edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and add `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` after `quiet-splash` inside the quote mark and then run `sudo update-grub` Let me know if this works and I will make it an answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 "[Ubuntu Base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates#Expanded_presentation_of_updates)" is any installed packages listed in `/usr/share/ubuntu-release-upgrader/DistUpgrade.cfg`

Comment: mchid, that didn't work. I get the same blinking cursor.

Also, strangely, I restored my backup and then tried updating with "Ubuntu Base" unchecked in the Updater and got the same problem as I did with ONLY "Ubuntu Base" checked. Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesKay you can examine the contents of /var/log/apt/history.log (a text file) to see what packages were updated in the last update.  If you [edit] your question and include that information, it might be very valuable. It seems that you may have narrowed down the issue to a small set of packages.